# lightbox not working in typo3 extension fs_media_gallery

Tags: jquery, typo3-7.6.x

I'm configure fs_media_gallery extension for image gallery in my website and also configure jh_magnificpopup for lightbox but i'm not able to open images in lightbox. Images always open in whole browser.

Comment: Have you checked the console ?

Comment: Yes, i had checked but there is no any errors or warning regarding this.

Comment: able to create fiddle or share the code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In template of fs_media_gallery extension,
Please check following two attribute exists in your link
data-lightbox="" & data-title="" ?

If not then please add this tags and check.

Answer (score 0):

It works with `typescript`...

```
plugin.tx_fsmediagallery.settings.album.lightbox.enable = 1
plugin.tx_fsmediagallery.settings.album.lightbox.styleClass = sd-lightbox
plugin.tx_fsmediagallery.settings.album.lightbox.relPrefix = sd-lightbox[{field:uid}]
```